# Get function import path

Tags: python, function, import, path

```
from pack.mod import f
```

How to get from object f information about import - `'pack.mod'`

I can get it using `f.__module__`
but if function def in module where i get this attribute (`f.__module__`) it return `'__main__'`. But i need real path here - `'pack.mod'`

I found this way to get this information:

```
inspect.getmodule(f).__file__
```

then i can sub start path from `sys.path`, replace `/` on `.` and get path like - `'pack.mod'`
But may be exist some more convenient way?

Comment: why do you need this to begin with?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What `inspect.getmodule(f)` does internally, per [inspect.py's sources](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/inspect.py?revision=75433&view=markup), is essentially `sys.modules.get(object.__module__)` -- I wouldn't call using that code directly "more convenient", though (beyond the "essentially" part, `inspect` has a lot of useful catching and correction of corner cases).

Why not call directly [inspect.getsourcefile(f)](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=getsourcefile#inspect.getsourcefile)?

**Edit**: reading between the lines it seems the OP is trying to do something like

```
python /foo/bar/baz/bla.py
```

and within `bla.py` (which is thus being run as `__main__`) determine "what `from` or `import` statement could a different main script use to import this function from within me?".

Problem is, the question is ill-posed, because there might not be **any** such path usable for the purpose (nothing guarantees the current main script's path is on `sys.path` when that different main script gets run later), there might be several different ones (e.g. both `/foo/bar` and `/foo/bar/baz` might be on `sys.path` and `/foo/bar/baz/__init__.py` exist, in which case `from baz.bla import f` and `from bla import f` might both work), and nothing guarantees that some *other*, previous `sys.path` item might not "preempt" the import attempt (e.g., say `/foo/bar/baz` is on `sys.path`, but before it there's also `/fee/fie/foo`, and a completely unrelated file `/fee/fie/foo/bla.py` also exists -- etc, etc).

Whatever the purpose of this kind of discovery attempt, I suggest finding an alternative architecture -- e.g., one where `from baz.bla import f` **is** actually executed (as the OP says at the start of the question), so that `f.__module__` is correctly set to `baz.bla`.

Comment: OK, but i need some native way to get info in format ready for importing, not file path witch i need to parse for extract info. It exists or i must parse path anyway?

Comment: The `__module__` attribute gives you that path -- you claim it gives `__main__`, but that will never happen when you've done, as you also say, `from path.mod import f` -- only if you're running the file as the main script instead of importing it, and that `from` statement means you **are** importing and so `__module__` works fine.

Comment: My goal to write logger. i hang it on function as decorator. It dumps all function args it called with at db, function name and module name also written - i need this information to restore function call later with this args on demand. To restore call i need load function before, and that why i need path to load it... I'am targeting that sys.path always same. Mb i need some another way to identify how to load function, m.b full file path and function name better...but in this case i need to analyze file path and sys.path to build valid import path...is it right?

Comment: If the function is defined in `__main__` when you log it, it had better be defined exactly the same place when you restore it (i.e, you clearly need to be running the same main script as well as having the same `sys.path`), so `from __main__ import f` in this case is the right answer.  No other "path" except `__main__` can ever possibly *guarantee* it will load the same function that `__main__` has defined, as I explained.  So just use the `__module__`, whether it's `__main__` or anything else, for your now-stated purposes.

Answer (score 11):

You want the `__name__` attribute from `__module__`:

```
In [16]: import inspect
In [17]: inspect.getmodule(MyObject).__name__
Out[17]: 'lib.objects.MyObject'
```

Comment: I'm a little surprised by your answer, I think the snippet isn't correct, it doesn't seem to be possible to get the result you are given, no matter if MyObject is a class (as the capitalization suggests) or a object instance (as the name suggests). See below.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Will's answer above https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712381/3166043 is incorrect, as commented:

```
cd /tmp/
mkdir test
cd test
mkdir lib
echo "class MyObject: pass" > lib/objects.py
touch lib/__init__.py
export PYTHONPATH=.
python3 -c 'import inspect; from lib.objects import MyObject; print(inspect.getmodule(MyObject).__name__)'
```

outputs:

```
lib.objects
```

and if I replace the `from lib.objects import MyObject` with `from lib.objects import MyObject as MyObjectClass; MyObject = MyObjectClass()`, I get the same results.

Comment: It's breaking changes in Python. to get the function/module's name `MyObject.__name__` or `obj = MyObject; obj.__name__`