# Retrieve string for unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-babel

Consider this code:

```
def get_some_text():
    return _(u"We need this text here")
```

What is the best way to write a unit test that makes sure the function returns this - referenced and translated by Babel - string?

This naive code would not contain a reference - so this are actually a different "Babel strings":

```
def test_get_some_text(self):
    self.assertEqual(get_some_text(), _(u"We need this text here"))
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "somehow referenced", could you explain? Also, what does the underscore do (is it a function defined elsewhere)?

Comment: I edited the question a bit. "_" is the babel way of marking a string for translation: http://babel.pocoo.org/docs/messages/

Answer (score 2):

If you're using flask-babel, don't mind using mocks, and you're only testing what `_` returns (i.e. `get_some_text` doesn't do any additional transformations on the result of `_`), then you can mock the return value of `_` and test that you get what you expect:

```
import mock


@mock.patch('gettext.ugettext')
def test_get_some_text(self, mock_ugettext):
  mock_ugettext.return_value = u'Hello World'

  self.assertEqual(get_some_text(), u'Hello World')
```

We know that `_` calls `ugettext` from [here](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask-babel/blob/master/flask_babel/__init__.py#L461), and if we drop an `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` line right before, we can hop into a python shell, call `get_some_text`, and use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18712381/5162842) to find the import path of `ugettext`, which turns out to be `gettext.ugettext`.

If you're only using babel, and you know the path to your translations directory, you might be able to [make your own translations](http://polib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#creating-po-catalogs-from-scratch) just for testing:

```
import os
import shutil

import polib    


os_locale = ''
translations_directory = '/absolute/path/to/your/translations'
# choose a locale that isn't already in translations_directory
test_locale = 'en_GB'

def setUp(self):
    mo_file_path = os.path.join(
        translations_directory,
        test_locale,
        'LC_MESSAGES',
        'messages.mo'
    )
    mo = polib.MOFile()
    entry = polib.MOEntry(
        msgid=u'We need this text here',
        msgstr='My favourite colour is grey'
    )
    mo.append(entry)
    mo.save(mo_file_path)

    # modify our locale for the duration of this test
    os_locale = os.environ.pop('LANG', 'en')
    os.environ['LANG'] = test_locale

def tearDown(self):
    # restore our locale
    os.environ['LANG'] = os_locale
    shutil.rmtree(os.path.join(translations_directory, test_locale))

def test_get_some_text(self):
    self.assertEqual(get_some_text(), u'My favourite colour is grey')
```

Comment: Since this was written, `_` has been modified and calls `flask_babel.gettext`. Now you should use `@mock.patch("flask_babel.gettext")` instead.